# Problem with snapshot of a "some View" property

Tags: swift, swiftui

To give the context, I am working on a course given by Udacity (I am a beginner!). In this course, there is a project about creating a Meme application where the user can select or take a picture and add top and bottom text on the image. Moreover, there is a background behind the image in gray color.

The idea is to share the meme created. To do so, I implemented a snapshot function as an extension for the View class :

```
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let view = controller.view
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize)
        
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation for the share button :

```
AnimatedActionButton(title: "Share", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up") {
    items.removeAll()
    let snapshot = meme.snapshot()
    items.append(snapshot)
    showingSharePage = true
}
```

The AnimatedActionButton is a simple code written to make button creation simple which I learnt in CS193p from Stanford.

Here is the meme property :

```
var meme: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            VStack {
                TextField("", text: $topText, onEditingChanged: { editing in
                    if editing && !topTextEdited {
                        self.$topText.wrappedValue = ""
                        topTextEdited = true
                    }
                })
                .font(.custom("HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40))
                .autocapitalization(UITextAutocapitalizationType.allCharacters)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 3/4)
                Group {
                    if let uiImage = uiImage {
                        Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    }
                }
                TextField("", text: $bottomText, onEditingChanged: { editing in
                    if editing && !bottomTextEdited {
                        self.$bottomText.wrappedValue = ""
                        bottomTextEdited = true
                    }
                })
                .font(.custom("HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40))
                .autocapitalization(UITextAutocapitalizationType.allCharacters)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 3/4)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is what I see on my device when simulating the app :
[image: Simulating the app]

Here is what I receive when sharing the meme through the application :
[image: Shared meme]

Why is it doing this ? What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: It might be because targetSize is different from the view bounds. In my experience it's better to create a new view for the hosting controller (instead of using the one displayed on screen) and set the frame manually. Content will be the same but will layout properly in the given size, instead of translating from current screen size.